# Trouble converting numbers to dates in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert the following numbers to dates in R:

[image]

Comment: Please provide the actual values instead of a picture.

Comment: `library(lubridate) 
date<-ymd(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `as.Date` with the correct format mask:

```
dates <- c(19801231, 19810130, 19810227)
as.Date(as.character(dates), format="%Y%m%d")

[1] "1980-12-31" "1981-01-30" "1981-02-27"
```

Note that if your `Names.Date` column already be text, then you can skip the extra conversion and just use:

```
as.Date(dates, format="%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lubridate package.

```
> library(lubridate)
> Names.Date <- c(19810130, 19810227, 19810331)
> Names.Date
[1] 19810130 19810227 19810331
> ymd(Names.Date)
[1] "1981-01-30" "1981-02-27" "1981-03-31"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `anydate`

```
library(anytime)
anydate(dates)
#[1] "1980-12-31" "1981-01-30" "1981-02-27"
```

#### data

```
dates <- c(19801231, 19810130, 19810227)
```